# fix layers of neural network

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

How can I fix layers of a neural network in tensorflow?

For example in this sample program, say if I know the second layer by training another neural network (say B). Can I use that as a fixed layer and calculate the first layer in the network below?

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

#layer 1
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 100]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100]))
y1 = tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1 #remove softmax

#layer 2
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100, 10]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y2 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y1, W2) + b2)

#output
y = y2
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify certain variables as not trainable, and you can initialize variables with some stored value. Something like:

```
W2 = tf.Variable(saved_weigths, trainable=False)
b2 = tf.Variable(saved_biases, trainable=False)
y2 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y1, W2) + b2)
```

where `saved_weights` and `saved_biases` contain your pre-learned weight matrix and bias vector respectively. For reference: [Variable docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable).